# How do I remove recently view products from list view using XML?

Tags: xml

this is my xml code:

```
    <catalog_category_default>
     <remove name="right.reports.product.viewed" />
    </catalog_category_default>
```

I am trying to remove the recently viewed products from all category and subcategories pages. How can I do that?

Comment: the code smeed to be right.can you please tell me where u have put this.

Comment: it is in the layout folder from my theme and I  cleared the cache from admin panel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At magento,***catalog_category_default*** handler is created on category page  whenever that  `category  is non- Anchor`.

**catalog_category_default** `does not exit`  at `Anchor category` means `layer navigate category`,

That you need fine a handler which is create both on `Anchor category` and `Non Anchor category`

Magento is ***automatically create few handler***  whenever  `loadLayout()`  called.

From their list, ***one of  handler***  is inserted  at current layout on basic of current  `controller action full Name` ***[Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::getFullActionName()]***.

That means ,whenever a  `category layout loaded`,that time a handler is created and it name is ***catalog_category_view*** .

***And it does not depends on Anchor field of category.***

so.you can use  ***catalog_category_view*** handler  for `removing recently viewed products from all category and subcategories pages`.
.

Comment: but what about subcategories?  In the subcategories  are still there if I use catalog_category_view or catalog_category_default

Comment: for all category & it subcategory... this handler are createing always..... but for research page you need to use `catalogsearch_result_index`

Comment: I used this : <catalog_category_default>
        <remove name="right.reports.product.viewed" />
    </catalog_category_default>
    <catalog_category_view>
     <remove name="right.reports.product.viewed" />
 </catalog_category_view>   and they are still there only in the subcategories . I don;t get it

Comment: it was the cached :| thx

Answer (score 3):

You should use a  different layout handle. Put it between `catalog_category_layered` instead

```
<catalog_category_layered>
    <remove name="right.reports.product.viewed" />
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to remove the block from all category list pages (layered or not):

```
<catalog_category_view>
    <remove name="right.reports.product.viewed" />
</catalog_category_view>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your category "isAnchor" (i.e. It has products in) it will need to be put in the **catalog_category_layered** handle instead.

As Amit has pointed out though, catalog_category_view will cover both.

Answer (score 0):

Goto `\app\design\frontend\default\theme\layout\reports.xml`

Comment Below line

```
<reference name="right">
            <block type="reports/product_viewed" before="right.permanent.callout" name="right.reports.product.viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />
            <block type="reports/product_compared" before="right.permanent.callout" name="right.reports.product.compared" template="reports/product_compared.phtml" />
        </reference>
```